# Getting a return status and string from a function

Tags: c++

I had an interesting situation earlier today while trying to refactor some code. The return value was a string and then compared inside the calling class method.

String comparison being expensive I figured out the return value could be a bool, but then the string had also an use in logging should an exception occur.

So one of my options was to have the function as

```
bool result = a.f(&status_string, other_args);
```

and then use status_string.

Second option:

```
std::pair<bool, string> result = a.f(other_args);
```

Yet a third option:

```
bool result = a.f(other_args) and then query for `a.get_status()` for the message.
```

Which one of these is the most elegant solution? Or maybe pass a callback to `a.f` via `boost::bind` and have that callback being passed the string but then the code is not loosely coupled any more.

Comment: Is that string used for anything but logging?

Comment: Just logging and no more.

Comment: Well then I think neither solution is elegant. Simply let the function do the logging and don't return  it from there in any way.

Comment: Using `pair` is generally a bad sign. Create a class with two members, and see what member functions might make sense on it?

Comment: @us2012 While I'm not entirely disagreeing, that can be harder to test. Also it potentially violates separation of concerns - why is a function whose job is to compute a value having to worry about logging?

Comment: @AlanStokes I see your point, but I'd say it applies to your suggestion of having it return a `class a { bool res; string msg; }`, too. Why would a function that computes stuff have to worry about any kind of messages at all?

Comment: @us 2012 Fair point. This may fall into the "Doctor it hurts when I do this! Don't do that then." category. Although generating the message is a separate issue from caring where the message goes.

Comment: It would be more interesting to discuss this case if action would be taken when status is bad. I am dealing with such a case where I have deloped a value with status that propagates the least favorable status. I have posted this question but I get no answer sigh .. Out of scope I know ... Want to get status of r= a+b+c when some of a+b+c is bad. Basically a value + status. To my experience a string is not a good status type ... Could post it again. Error handling seems to be unpopular. Removed question when no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand on my comment above.

If, as far as the logic of the program is concerned, the result of the function is `bool`ean and you only need to log a status message, there is no point of returning the message and letting the caller do the logging because it introduces irrelevant parameters in the interface.

Instead, let the function do the logging:

```
bool myfun(someobj s) {
  ...
  if (cond1) {
    logger.log(message);
    return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}
```

---

Another perspective on this problem is: Why do you need to have more than two message strings at all? If your function has two possible results, there are only two possible things to log, in which case this can be easily handled by the caller:

```
if (myfun(s)) {
  dostuff();
  logger.log(msg1);
}
else
  ...
```

If there are more than two possible results, maybe you shouldn't return a `bool` at all, but an `enum`? Or even use exception handling?

Answer (score 0):

If the message is only used "if there is an exception", then using the `get_status` model would be the best solution, since the exception is (hopefully) a rare occurrence, rather than something that happens on a regular basis. So why burden the common code with maintaining (creating, copying, destroying) the string, when it is not commonly used?